# pandas dataframe create html table with horizontal border for totals

Tags: python, css, pandas, html-table

I want to add a horizontal line above the final row.  I've included my solution below but interested to hear if there's a better way.  It would be nice for the horizontal line to extend into the index to cover the "Total" label.   (My example also does row totals FWIW)

I'm guessing it might be possible to do this with `pivot_table` or `crosstab` but I didn't need the additional aggregation; and it doesn't seem to do the borders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import HTML
import functools

def borderTop(strRow, srRow):
    #print(strRow, type(sRow), sRow.name)
    if srRow.name == strRow:
        return [ "border-top: 1pt solid black; font-weight: bold" for sCol in srRow ]
    else:
        return [""] * len(srRow)

np.random.seed(0)  # to make the numbers reproducible
dfBody = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,3)))

# make a column of row totals and append it on the right
srRowTots = dfBody.sum(axis=1).astype(int)
srRowTots.name="Total"
dfBody2 = pd.concat([dfBody, srRowTots], axis=1)

# make a row of column totals and append to the bottom
srColTots = dfBody2.sum().astype(int)
srColTots.name="Total"
dfBodyTots = pd.concat([dfBody2, srColTots.to_frame().T])

# Display it, making the total column and row bold and bordered
dfBodyTots.style\
     .set_properties(subset=['Total'], **{'font-weight': 'bold', "border-left": "1pt solid black"})\
     .apply(functools.partial(borderTop, "Total"), axis=1)
```

[image]